# How to write dictionary keys to a new text file in python?

Tags: python, file-io, dictionary

I have data in dictionary. How can I write all of the keys to a file(.txt) format?

Comment: What have you tried? Which version of python are you using (2 or 3)? Perhaps you could give us a sample dictionary, and then show what you expect the file representation to look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dict.keys()` to extract keys from dictionary:

```
d = {'foo' : 1, 'bar' : 2}
fname = 'keys.txt'

with open(fname, 'w') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(d.keys()))
    f.write('\n') # newline at the end of file

print "Keys saved to {}.".format(fname)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ab={'engy':'011199887765',
    'wafa2':'87878857578',
    'heba':'6677553636'}
with open('D:\glo.txt','w') as f:
    for name, mobile in ab.items():
        print ('Contact %s at %s' % (name, mobile))
        f.write(name)
```

this is just an example , you need do some modification.